# An item with the same name already exists in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I know its been asked already , but this time the solutions are not working for me .
I had some framework that was dragged to Xcode without copying it .
than i have removed it from desktop , and `Xcode` shows error that its missing . (till now ok).

So, i have removed the `.framework` of this file, from the frameworks folder in the project.
Now i can't add it again, because :

```
an item with the same name already exists
```

its not there,i can't find it in the project, and can't add it again.

What could i miss here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go to the target settings for the target which included it, click on "Build Phases" and twirl open the section labeled "Link Binary With Libraries" you'll probably see it in the list of linked libraries. Simply select the old one and press the "-" button to remove it.

Answer (score 33):

Also- Check your **project folder**. Sometimes your file doesn't get deleted out of that folder even though Xcode is showing that file not there.

Answer (score 3):

I tried all of the answers above but the only problem is that xcode doesn't delete the folder.

So make sure the folder is delete in the project directory.

Answer (score 2):

If you just remove the reference of item, It's not really deleted item from your folder. You could go to the project folder and delete it.

[click "remove the reference" and it's not deleted completely](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHEVf.png)

[Go to folder of your project and remove it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHNbq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've been breaking my head trying to figure out this error. This happens when you delete a file/framework from your Xcode project. Then you try to read and you get that annoying error that the files already exists. Here i what i did.

1. I looked to make sure that the frameworks weren't in any of my group folders.
2. Go to build phases - link binary with Libraries. (You probably won't see your frameworks here here either).
3. I simply just dragged the frameworks underneath Link Binary With Libraries and it worked -____-

I didn't do anything else. *Magic*